# How to create a funnel with an event goal in Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible? It seems that I have to make the final goal a destination(?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google analytics support Funnel visualisation and goal flow reporting only for goals of type **url destination** and you will not be able to use these for **event goals**. An option that you can try is to create **virtual pageviews** for tracking the steps instead of event tracking and then you can setup a destination goal and funnel with the virtual page urls.